# Can't get train and test sets

Tags: cross-validation

I applied k-fold cross validation to split data into train and test sets.
But when I want to get train and test sets I have these errors:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Thanks for your help.

```
y = df_dummies['Churn'].values
X = df_dummies.drop(columns = ['Churn'])

 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
features = X.columns.values
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaler.fit(X)
X = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X))
X.columns = features 

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf=KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True)

for train,test in kf.split(X):
print("%s %s" % (train,test))


for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]   
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
CLF = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on training set:          {:.2f}'
 .format(CLF.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
 .format(CLF.score(X_test, y_test)))  
NameError: name 'y_train' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi Sergio0606, welcome to stackoverflow.com, this question doesn't seem to belong here. Have you seen the sister site cross-validated? https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm a new guy in stack overflow. I have not seen it. Tbw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `df_dummies['Churn'].values` returns an array not a dataframe. But you are trying to get attributes from an array which don't exist. The `iloc` function is in `pandas.DataFrame`.

Use `y = df_dummies['Churn']` instead.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc

PS: I don't know how these type of questions could be migrated to a sister site. Perhaps, someone who knows that could migrate this to cross-validated please.